# Is there a way to refactor this code to one line?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and while I've had some success with one line refactoring before, this one in particular is stumping me and I feel like I'm missing something very fundamental in understanding why this does not work.

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
newfilenames = []
for names in filenames:
    if ".hpp" in names:
        newfilenames.append(names[:-3] + "h")
    else:
        newfilenames.append(names)
print(newfilenames) 
# Should be ["program.c", "stdio.h", "sample.h", "a.out", "math.h", "hpp.out"]

newfilenames.append(names[:-3] + "h") for names in filenames if ".hpp" in names else newfilenames.append(names))
print(newfilenames)
```

The initial code tests fine but when refactoring to a single line I keep getting syntax error at the else location. As mentioned, I'm new, so while a solution would be great I'm really looking for an explanation or to be pointed to literature that would better explain what I'm not grasping if possible.

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: " I've had some success with one line refactoring before" one-line refactoring is not a thing. It is **very important to understand** that trying to fit your code into one-line is *not a good metric to aim for*. Code should be *readable*, avoid trivial inefficiencies, and maintainable. Being "one line" is not valuable.

Comment: In this case, you **could** use a list comprehension, `newfiles = [names[:-3] + "h" if ".hpp" in names else names for names in filenames]` but it is very important to understand, the loop you have **is perfectly fine and pythonic**

Comment: And this doesn't work because `newfilenames.append(names[:-3] + "h") for names in filenames if ".hpp" in names else newfilenames.append(names))` is simply not correct syntax. It seems like you are confused with for-loops and list comprehensions

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Thanks for the quick reply. I'm glad you said that about the one-line codes not being a good metric to aim for. I was concerned it was.

Comment: I hope you're just doing this for fun and not because you think it looks more professional.  Good code should read like a good book. Take your time, break it down, use lots of functions with long descriptive names, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```py
newfilenames = ['{}h'.format(name[:-3]) if ".hpp" in name else name for name in filenames]

#result
['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'hpp.out']
```

the method name is List Comprehension u can read it [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)